# How to deploy a symfony 3 project on Aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and in web application deploying in general, and I'm trying to deploy my Symfony 3.4 application using Elastic Beanstalk.
So i tried to follow these instructions :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-symfony-tutorial.html

the problem that i have always this message when i click to the url :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

My server specs:

64bit Amazon Linux running PHP 7.3 and 2.9.6 plateforme version.

I also followed this publication but I couldn't solve the problem :

[aws beanstalk 403 error while deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578567/aws-beanstalk-403-error-while-deploying)

and when i add `/public` in the document root i have this error and the application couldn't deploy:

```
Following services are not running: proxy.
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you added to the Configuration this?

Document root: /public

Comment: Hello yes i tried to add /public in Elastic Beanstalk>Environnements>ApplicationName>Configuration>document root                       and in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ,
for symfony 3 in the document root is /web.

Thank you.