# Laravel app on elastic Beanstalk, api error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

2 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, error while trying to access the elasticBeanstalk hosted app

I tried to access the /public but this error was there. Nginx config was also changed but nothing fruitful

Comment: Do this answer your question :- [aws beanstalk 403 error while deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578567/aws-beanstalk-403-error-while-deploying)